# Layout stretching when dismissing DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-dialogfragment

I have an Activity that has the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_menu_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        // ICONS

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/temperatura_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="184dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <com.github.pavlospt.CircleView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/reading_value"
            android:layout_width="192dp"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_item_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_item_black_24px"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_item_btn_description" />

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_behavior="iconsOnly"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_navbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `add_item_btn` has an event on click that creates a **full-screen** *(edited to add this information)* `DialogFragment` to insert the item information and add it to local database. The following code shows how I create the `DialogFragment`:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
InsertItemDialogFragment fragment = new InsertItemDialogFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

The problem is that when I `dismiss()` the created fragment, the activity layout stretches, in a way that the `BottomBar` goes half behind the on-screen button bar (see images).

[image]
[image]

I tried changing the `FragmentTransaction` (from `android.R.id.content` to `R.id.main_content`, when `main_content` was the id of the root `RelativeLayout`) with no success. I also tried using 2 different implementations of the Material Design Bottom Navigation Bar, but both had the same behaviour.

Comment: found the solution?

Comment: Not yet. The solution presented by @azizbekian did not solve my problem, as commented in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer! I don't actually know why, since I have almost no experience with `CoordinatorLayout`, but switching the root Layout of the `FragmentDialog` to `LinearLayout` solved the problem.

Comment: If someone can explain it properly, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but not with my custom dialog. I am facing issue in system dialog the one for asking runtime permission. When I click given buttons in dialog it works perfectly but when I dismiss dialog using back button it streches my layout as you shown in your screenshots. And we can't do anything with system dialog.

Comment: Did you try adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in your coordinatorlayout?

Comment: I had it when using `CoordinatorLayout` and kept it in the current `LinearLayout` of the FragmentDialog.

Answer (score 1):

First: Your are changing your Activity to fullscreen and calling to add the fragment. After dismissing the dialog you have to make the activity restore its layout the same way you did to set it as fullscreen but this time as a normal screen. The space you see there is the space use by the android's systems bar.

Second: Don't use relative layout. Use a linear layout to layout your activity learn to use weights and use  if you need too.

Third: Why are you using a coordinator layout in your Dialog fragment. You don't need to.

Fourth: Android has its own bottom bar https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html Use it. They even have a working example and template you can see from Android Studio.

It is really hard to know what is wrong with your app with the information you provided

Comment: Thanks for all points! Let me try to explain them: (i) I didn't noticed this, but changing exclusively the `CoordinatorLayout` for `LinearLayout` solved my problem; (ii) I don't get the point of not using `RelativeLayout`, since I read in a lot of places that there's no real loss in using it; (iii) I used it because of the example I got from; (iv) I aim to switch every lib I'm using to the widget from Support Library, just didn't have enough time yet.

Comment: You should have the coordinator layout in your Activity, not in your DialogFragment.  Or, you can have in both if you want too. I don't see the point on displaying a full screen dialog fragment, when you can have another new activity to input data.

Comment: Since the input data is completely related to the information of the `Activity` and not self-sufficient, I thought it would make more sense to build it as a `DialogFragment`, instead of a new `Activity`.

Comment: Read this.https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/index.html. In the future for instance, you might want to implement a layout for tablets, that what you are doing won't work or would look ugly. Implement that same feature using just fragments / activities.